# Call Child function from Parent React Native - TypeError cannot read property of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Parent Component which has a Filter Component and the Filter Component has a FilterBox Component with a button on it.
Parent > Filter > FilterBox
FilterBox has a button which on click calls onButtonPress Function.
I want to call this onButtonPress function from Filter Component.
Tried using refs also tried binding the function in constructor. Still getting errors.

```
 class Filter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }
    render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <FilterBox
            //props
            ref = {this.child}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={()=>this.child.current.onButtonPress()}/>
        </View>

    )
}
 class FilterBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onButtonPress = this.onButtonPress.bind(this);
  }
  onButtonPress = () =>{
    console.log("Hi")
  }
}
```

I get a cannot read property 'onButtonPress' of null

Comment: If FilterBox wrapped by an HOC, if so which one

Comment: didnt get u. FilterBox is not wrapped around any HOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. I reproduce it in react so convert buttons to TouchableOpacity and onPress to onClick.

What it does is pass a function from filter to filterbox as a prop and when you call that function from componentDidMount of filterbox it set the state of filter component and give onButtonPress function to the this.state.propFunc.

```
class Filter extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.child = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        propFunc: null
    }
    this.funcToPass = this.funcToPass.bind(this)
}

funcToPass(fn) {
    this.setState({ propFunc: fn })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <FilterBox
                funcToPass={this.funcToPass}
            />
            {this.state.propFunc != null && <button onClick={this.state.propFunc} />}
        </div>

    )
}
}
class FilterBox extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}
onButtonPress = () => {
    console.log("Hi")
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.funcToPass(this.onButtonPress)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bud. Will try.

Comment: Is it the right approach to such a problem or just an escape hatch?

Comment: I dont think this will work because the function onButtonPress has some dependencies linked to the FilterBox Class. If i pass the function as a state, it wont work. The dependencies will be undefined

Comment: I believe there could be better approaches, but in your case this approach won't hurt you. What are these dependencies of onButtonPress? Since, it is defined in FilterBox class it has a closure on its lexical spoce. For example, it can still change the state of FilterBox class by this.setstate. Think this:  class FilterBox extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   hello: 1
  }
 }
 onButtonPress = () => {
  this.setState({hello: this.state.hello + 1})
  console.log(this.state.hello)
 }   in each click console will print one more even it is called in Filter.

Comment: if using refs seems a better approach to you you can use it like this <FilterBox
     funcToPass={this.funcToPass}
     ref="filterBox"
    />
    {this.refs.filterBox && <button onClick={this.refs.filterBox.onButtonPress} />}